# ndims returned from imread

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am picking up an image from a file folder. It is of size 128*128. For this, I am using the following lines of code :

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select the Cover Image');
file = fullfile(PathName,FileName);
disp(['User selected : ', file]);
cover = imread(file);
%cover = double(cover);
if ndims(cover) ~= 3
    msgbox('The cover image must be colour');
break;
end
figure(1);
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(uint8(cover),[]);
title('Cover image');

%num specifies the number of Iterations for the Arnold Transform
num = input('\nEnter the value of num: ');
encrypted = arnold(cover,num);
imshow(encrypted);
```

The function `arnold` is as follows :

```
function [ out ] = arnold( in, iter )
    if (ndims(in) ~= 2)
        error('Oly two dimensions allowed');
    end
    [m n] = size(in);
    if (m ~= n)
        error(['Arnold Transform is defined only for squares. ' ...
        'Please complete empty rows or columns to make the square.']);
    end
    out = zeros(m);
    n = n - 1;
    for j=1:iter
        for y=0:n
            for x=0:n
                p = [ 1 1 ; 1 2 ] * [ x ; y ];
                out(mod(p(2), m)+1, mod(p(1), m)+1) = in(y+1, x+1);
            end
        end
        in = out;
        imwrite(uint8(in),'Enc.jpg');
    end
end
```

I am getting the following error :

```
??? Error using ==> arnold at 9
Only two dimensions allowed

Error in ==> deepoo at 20
    encrypted = arnold(cover,num);
```

Can someone explain the purpose of ndims ?? I am a bit confused.
if `ndims=3`, then is the image colored ? and if `ndims=2`, does that mean that the image is not colored ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly correct.

Color images are read in to MATLAB as 3 channels (R,G, and B) so the 3rd dimension is each of these channels. If the image is grayscale, it will be only 2 dimensions. Because in grayscale, the R,G, and B values are guaranteed to be the same. There are various ways to go from color to grayscale (`rgb2gray` for one) - and then to go from grayscale to color, you simply need to replicate the same 2D matrix into 3D. One of the shortest way to do this is with the repmat function.

Below is a very long (but hopefully clear way of converting grayscale to 3D)

```
colorImg(:,:,1)=grayScaleImg;
colorImg(:,:,2)=grayScaleImg;
colorImg(:,:,3)=grayScaleImg;
```

and you can just do it all in one:

```
colorImg(:,:,1:3)=grayScaleImg;
```

Hopefully this helps a little!

Some MATLAB Documentation is here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html

And in particular (3rd paragraph)

> The return value A is an array containing the image data. If the file
>   contains a grayscale image, A is an M-by-N array. If the file contains
>   a truecolor image, A is an M-by-N-by-3 array. For TIFF files
>   containing color images that use the CMYK color space, A is an
>   M-by-N-by-4 array. See TIFF in the Format-Specific Information section
>   for more information.

Comment: I used a color image. Its had 3 dimensions. on converting it into greyscale, the number of dimensions shown was 1. I am still confused.. how many dimensions does a black and white image has ?

Comment: 1 dimension, are you sure? How did you convert it? black and white image has two dimensions, though if its a true black and white image and MATLAB recognizes it as such, it will read it in a logical matrix and the values will only be 0 and 1. It's pretty much impossible for a .jpg to be JUST black and white though due to compression

Comment: @competesingh I would have to see strong evidence to believe that you're getting a 1-dimensional image. I think you're mixing up dimensions and color channels.