# sobel filter for horizontal by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

i wrote this code for apply a horizontal sobel filter on my image to detect horizontal edge.but i have this error :"
Error using edge
Expected input number 1, I, to be two-dimensional.

Error in edge>parse_inputs (line 482)
validateattributes(I,{'numeric','logical'},{'real','nonsparse','2d'},mfilename,'I',1);
"

why it shows errors ?

here is my code :

```
h = imread('chest.jpg');
imshow(h);
BW = edge (h,'sobel','vertical');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ndims returned from imread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811523/ndims-returned-from-imread)

Comment: Your jpg imag must have 3 channels (Red, Green, Blue), i.e., it is an $n \times m \times 3$ array. Thus, if you want to work on, say, the blue channel, you will have to select h1=h(:,:,1) and then work on h1 : BW = edge (h1,'sobel','vertical');